# Laravel Queue Driver not calling handle() on jobs, but queue:listen daemon is logging jobs as processed

Tags: php, laravel, server, queue, forge

I've taken over a **Laravel 5.2** project where `handle()` was being called successfully with the `sync` queue driver.

I need a driver that supports `dispatch(..)->delay(..)` and have attempted to configure both `database` and `beanstalkd`, with numerous variations,  unsuccessfully - `handle()` is no longer getting called.

## Current setup

I am using Forge for server management and have set up a daemon, which is automatically kept running by Supervisor, for this command:

> php /home/forge/my.domain.com/envoyer/current/**artisan queue:listen** --sleep=3 --tries=3
>
> > I've also tried queue:work, naming 'database/beanstalkd', with and without specifying --sleep, --tries , --deamon

I have [an active beanstalkd worker running on forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCXx2.png).

I have set the default driver to `beanstalkd` in `\config\queue.php` and `QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd` in my `.env` from within Envoyer, which has worked fine for other environment variables.

After build deployment Envoyer runs the following commands successfully:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:restart
```

## Debug information

My `queue:listen` daemon produces log within .forge **says it processed a job!**

> [2017-07-04 08:59:13] Processed: App\Jobs\GenerateRailwayReport

Where that job class is defined like this:

```
class GenerateRailwayReport extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    protected $task_id;

    public function __construct($task_id)
    {
        $this->task_id = $task_id;
        clock("GenerateRailwayReport constructed"); // Logs Fine
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        clock("Handling Generation of railway report"); // Never Logs
        //Bunch of stuff all commented out during my testing
    }

    public function failed(Exception $e)
    {
        clock("Task failed with exception:"); // Never Logs
        clock($e);
    }
}
```

My beanstalkd worker log within .forge has **no output** in it.

Nothing in my failed_jobs table.

-Really, really appreciate any help at this point!

Comment: Post your `handle` method code.

Comment: @ayip - Posted all class code now - Unfortunately you can see I've commented all the complicated stuff out for testing, it's just a single line now using clockworks logger that never appears in the log/chrome extension.

Comment: @HollyGrant did you find a solution?

Comment: No luck with this one ? Dealing with the same myself.